# How to determine if an optional function has been passed into an Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that displays some data but I want to user of the directive to be able to control how that data is displayed. I would like to allow a user to be able control the display using one of three options.

1. pass in a string to use for the display
2. pass in a function that will be called to generate the string
3. or just show the raw data

I can't post the code for the entire directive (NDA and all) but it is a directive for showing a ring chart using D3. The number in the middle is the piece of data in question. So assuming the ring chart is showing a percentage, I may want the text in the center to say 55%. So assuming myValue is a property on the scope and is set to 55, here is what I would like to do:

```
<div ring-chart total="100"
             remaining="{{myValue}}"
             center-number-class="center-number-sm"
             remaining-color="#0F79C0"
             used-color="#C1D3E6"
             chart-width="45"
             chart-height="45"
             ring-thickness="3"
             label-text="{{myValue}}%"></div>
```

which would show 55%
or do:

```
<div ring-chart total="100"
             remaining="{{myValue}}"
             center-number-class="center-number-sm"
             remaining-color="#0F79C0"
             used-color="#C1D3E6"
             chart-width="45"
             chart-height="45"
             ring-thickness="3"
             label-function="ringLabelFunction(remaining)"></div>
```

which would show whatever ringLabelFunction(value) returns
and finally have the option to do:

```
<div ring-chart total="100"
             remaining="{{myValue}}"
             center-number-class="center-number-sm"
             remaining-color="#0F79C0"
             used-color="#C1D3E6"
             chart-width="45"
             chart-height="45"
             ring-thickness="3"></div>
```

which would just show 55.

In the directive I have

```
    ...
scope: {
    total:"@",
    remaining:"@",
    valueSuffix: "@",
    centerNumberClass: "@",
    suffixClass: "@",
    remainingColor: "@",
    totalColor: "@",
    chartWidth: "@",
    chartHeight: "@",
    ringThickness: "@",
    labelFunction: "&",
    labelText:"@"
},
link:function($scope, element, attrs) {
    var labelContent;
    if ($scope.labelText) {
     labelContent =  $scope.labelText;
    } else if ($scope.labelFunction) { //<-- this is always true
     labelContent = $scope.labelFunction({remaining:$scope.remaining});
    } else { //so I never get to this
     labelContent = $scope.remaining;
    }

   ...
}

...
```

So, in short I am looking for a way to determine if $scope.labelFunction has actually been set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have link `attrs`. Just check if `label-function` is defined and its value refers to `function`

```
link:function($scope, element, attrs) {

   if(attrs.labelFunction != undefined && typeof(attrs.onStuff) == 'function'){
        scope.$eval(attrs.labelFunction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... it also seems to work with just `if(attrs.labelFunction != undefined) {...}`

Comment: @mcgraphix right bu user can type value name instead function

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it's a function:

```
} else if ($scope.labelFunction && typeof($scope.labelFunction) == "function") {
```