# Directive default attribute functions

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have an Angular directive that accepts attributes in the form of a function such as:

```
<this-directive the-function="hello()"></this-directive>
```

Which is then passed from the parent scope to the directive scope.

Sometimes I want to provide a function to this directive, but other times I don't and I just want to use a default function defined within the directive. How would I go about this?

I've had a look around, but I can't figure out a reliable way to check if a function has been passed to the directive or not.

Comment: This response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360839/how-to-determine-if-an-optional-function-has-been-passed-into-an-angular-directi is what I was looking for.

Comment: Yeah. Using the '&' binding strategy with undefined check for function in directive link will resolve the issue.